# Copy file from FTP with lastwritetime

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

How to copy file from ftp with saving original lastwritetime, not current time?

This download file, and set lastwritetime current time.

```
$Login = 'anonymous'
$Pass  = ''
$url   = "ftp://ftp.intel.com/readme.txt"
$local = "C:\docs\readme.txt"

$WC = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$WC.Credentials = [Net.NetworkCredential]::new($Login,$Pass)
$WC.downloadFile($url,$local)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to set the "server last write time", you need to retrieve at the same time as you retrieve the actual file.
Once you have both, you can update the local last update time with the time from the server.

**Edit**: I updated the script to make two requests. The first one is fast as it only retrieves the remote file Timestamp. Once we have it, we download the file to the disk and update the last modified date for the file.

```
$LocalFile = "c:\temp\readme2.txt"

$url = "ftp://ftp.intel.com/readme.txt"

#Retrieve the DateTimestamp of the remote file
$WR = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$WR.Method = [Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::GetDateTimestamp
$WR.Credentials = [Net.NetworkCredential]::new("anonymous","")
$Response = $WR.GetResponse()
$RemoteLastModifiedTime = $Response.LastModified

#Retrieve the file content
$WR1 = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$WR1.Method = [Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::DownloadFile
$WR1.Credentials = [Net.NetworkCredential]::new("anonymous","")
$Response1 = $WR1.GetResponse()
$ResponseStream = $Response1.GetResponseStream()
# Create the target file on the local system and the download buffer
$LocalFileFile = New-Object IO.FileStream ($LocalFile,[IO.FileMode]::Create)
[byte[]]$ReadBuffer = New-Object byte[] 1024
# Loop through the download
do {
    $ReadLength = $ResponseStream.Read($ReadBuffer,0,1024)
    $LocalFileFile.Write($ReadBuffer,0,$ReadLength)
}
while ($ReadLength -ne 0)
$LocalFileFile.Close()

#Update the Last Modified DateTime
$(Get-Item $LocalFile).LastWriteTime=$RemoteLastModifiedTime
```

Comment: I tested your script and it works for changing time ; but i have always 0 bytes in size Why ??

Comment: @Hackoo, thx for pointing it out. I was only retrieving the timestamp on the first version of the script. I uploaded it to make two requests
1. Get the remote file timestamp
2. Download the file
3. Apply the timestamp to the downloaded file

Comment: I thought about this way, but i have one problem with it. GetDateTimestamp returns to me 20 april 2020 13:36:00, but when i check this file in explorer, i see 20 april 2020 3:36:00. How i can get correct time(3:36:00) for file? I have code on VBScript that can copy file from ftp with original time(3:36:00), but i think, that Posh is able to do this too.

Comment: Depending on the timezone you're located in, the time returned for this file could be different. In my case, I receive Monday, April 20, 2020 12:36:00 PM.

Comment: I understand, that it depending on the timezone. But how to get original time? Explorer  somehow can see exactly 3:36:00 ...

Comment: Ok, I believe that because the daylight settings are applied, you see 3.36.
Instead of using $(Get-Item $LocalFile).LastWriteTime, can you try 
$(Get-Item $LocalFile).LastWriteTimeUtc ?

Comment: My timezone is UTC+3. LastWriteTimeUtc returns 10:36:00 (13-3). That is not 3:36:00. I think, that 10:36 must be correct time, but explorer shows 3:36, it is mystery. Can u get with this the same time as in the explorer? Btw, what time u see in explorer of this file, 3:36 too?

Comment: My Timezone is UTC+2.
The return of the GetDateTimestamp (ps) is Monday, April 20, 2020 12:36:00 PM
I assign it to the LastWriteTime property, and it shows ‎Monday, ‎April ‎20, ‎2020, ‏‎12:36:00 PM in the Explorer.

If you add this to your script, you'll see both times.
"UTC: "+ $(Get-Item $LocalFile).LastWriteTimeUtc
"Local :"+ $(Get-Item $LocalFile).LastWriteTime